# How to make configurable settings in Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am currently developing an Azure Logic App. For many actions, I am currently using hard-coded values (like, email address in Send Email Action, or sharepoint site in Create Sharepoint file, etc). I want to make them configurable, and avoid using hard-coded values as much as possible.
Is there any way in Azure Logic App to create and use configurable values. (just like what we do with App.Config in .NET apps)?

Thanks

Comment: Is it related to Azure functions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logic Apps have native support for parameters. You must declare all parameters under the 'parameters' section of the definition, and can then provide values at time of deployment. You can also specify default as part of the  declaration.

You can then use the `@parameters('parameterName')` expression in order to reference a parameter within the logic app definition.

See [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/mt643789.aspx) for full documentation.